# I am referring "bootstrap" from "node_modules" in "angular.json" But the styles are not applying when I do it with an example

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I just created a new angular app where I installed bootstrap and Jquery. If I test it, with an example of a button, it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Above is the angular file where I have edited the stlyles.

Comment: Did you restarted your server?

Comment: @SavanPadaliya Yes I did. I restarted code as well.

Comment: Remove `/` from scripts in bootstrap declaration.

Comment: In the scripts is not bootstrap.min.css, is bootstrap.min.js

Comment: @SavanPadaliya I saw that after posting, sorry for the mistake but it actually didnt work :/

Comment: @Eliseo It didnt work as well..

Comment: Check if this packages exists in node_modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be an issue with path. Can you update path and try this : "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"